# php array_search and unset multidimensional array

Tags: php

I'm trying to search through array and unset some elements if they are present in other array.

```
[scores] => Array
    (
        [1100190] => 0.15783204288267
        [1100213] => 0.15893037336024
        [2100230] => 0.16258444005331
        [1100516] => 0.16554697418536
        [1100973] => 0.16967437235894
    )

[explanation codes] => Array
    (
        [1100190] => 0
        [1100213] => 0
        [2100230] => 0
        [1100516] => 0
        [1100973] => 0
    )
```

So, I want for example key "[1100190]" to be removed. This is what I have for now:

```
// filter out keys we don't want
for($j=0; $j < count($filterData); $j++) {
    $position = array_search($filterData[$j], $recs);
    if($position != false) {
        foreach($recs as $key => $arr) {
            unset($recs[$key][$position]);
        }
    }
 }
```

In $filterData I have for example: 11111, 1100190. I'm not getting anything for $position when I try to echo it and my filter is not working.
Thanks in advance.

Solution:

```
foreach($recs as $key => $arr) {
    $position = array_search($key, $filterData);
    if($position != false) {
        unset($recs[$key]);
    }
}
```

This is what did the trick, thanks for help, especially keune.

Comment: You can search the key with: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: is $recs an array containing scores and explanation codes?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested I would use [`array key exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
foreach ($filterData as $k => $v)
{
    if (array_key_exists($k, $recs))
    {
        unset($recs[$k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the search in every key of the `$recs` array. Try this:

```
for($j=0; $j < count($filterData); $j++) {
    foreach($recs as $key => $arr) {
        $position = array_search($filterData[$j], $arr);
        if($position !== false) {
            unset($recs[$key][$position]);
        }
    }
}
```